# image scaling in loop using python OpenCV

Tags: python, loops, opencv, io, path

I am new to Python and I am having a really hard time figuring out how to transform what I got here into a loop. As you can see here I am doing a basic image scaling to 3 different images (from mask_0001.png to mask_0003.png), but I will have more than 100 to go later on, so I will have to do it in a loop I guess. (from 0004.png to 0150.png )

Here is the code I just wrote:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C://Users//user//Desktop//research//images//Mask//set1//set1_mask_0001.png")
res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imwrite('0.25_mask_set1_0001.png', res)


img = cv2.imread("C://Users//user//Desktop//research//images//Mask//set1//set1_mask_0002.png")
res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imwrite('0.25_mask_set1_0002.png', res)


img = cv2.imread("C://Users//user//Desktop//research//images//Mask//set1//set1_mask_0003.png")
res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imwrite('0.25_mask_set1_0003.png', res)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops `i` from 1 to 150, setting the mask to `i`.

Python 2

```
for i in range(1,151):
    img = cv2.imread("C://Users//user//Desktop//research//images//Mask//set1//set1_mask_" + str(i).zfill(4) +".png")
    res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imwrite('0.25_mask_set1_' + str(i).zfill(4) + '.png', res)
```

Python 3

Instead of using `str(i).zfill(4)`, try `format(i, '04d')`

You should verify the behaviour, particularly with my use of `i` in `cv2.imwrite` to make sure it works with your problem

Comment: Thank you! But I got a question: according to your code, the 10th image is going to be 00010.png, however, the correct path should be 0010. Not sure if it is still going to work bruh.